# Allegro 5 strange behavior on drawing more scaled bitmap

Tags: c, bitmap, draw, allegro, allegro5

I was trying to create a card solitaire in C with Allegro 5.

```
void deck_printout(deck*d)
{
  int i;
  al_clear_to_color(stdcolor);
  for(i=0;i<40;i++){
     al_draw_scaled_bitmap(d->cards[i].img,
                           d->cards[i].xpos,
                           d->cards[i].ypos,
                           SWID,
                           SHEI,
                           d->cards[i].xpos,
                           d->cards[i].ypos,
                           DWID, DHEI, 0);
     //printf("%f %f\n",d->cards[i].xpos,d->cards[i].ypos);
     //al_draw_scaled_bitmap(d->cards[i].img,0,0,SWID,SHEI,0,0,DWID,DHEI,0);
     //al_draw_bitmap(d->cards[i].img,d->cards[i].xpos,d->cards[i].ypos,0);
  }
}
```

This function shuld draw all cards to the display. xpos and ypos are set correctly for each card, SWID and SHEI are 225x315 and DWID and DHEI are 80x112.

The `printf()` suggests me that the position of cards is ok, al_draw_bitmap suggests me that this problem may be caused by the scaling.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of jumbled playing cards]

Comment: have you tried without scaling?

Comment: yes, using al_draw_bitmap, cards are overlapped, because they are big and I use the position for the cards scaled, but there isn't that bad effect.

Comment: ok, in d->cards[i].img I put the scaled bitmap how here:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048136/loading-a-bitmap-image-to-a-certain-size

I solved for now.